# How to optimize MSSQL CASE WHEN queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, select

Here's a sample of my code:

```
SET @variable_out = 
'Report: '
+ CASE WHEN (SELECT name FROM person WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE person_id = @person_id) != ''
  THEN 'Name: ' + (SELECT name FROM person WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE person_id = @person_id) + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
  ELSE 'Name: not found' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
END
+ CASE WHEN (SELECT home_phone FROM person WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE person_id = @person_id) != ''
  THEN 'Phone #: ' + (SELECT home_phone FROM person WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE person_id = @person_id) + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
  ELSE 'Phone #: not found' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
END
```

etc...

As you can see, I am redundantly performing two selects for each CASE WHENE... of the variable that I am constructing, and I would love to collapse this down to only one select for each line.

The only solution I know of would be to create a unique variable for CASE WHEN..., run all of the selects before hand, and then if the variables aren't empty, concat them into @variable_out.

Is there a more clever way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE  @name the_same_datatype_as_name_field_from_person_table --Ex. VARCHAR(100)
    ,@home_phone the_same_datatype_as_homephone_field_from_person_table; --Ex. VARCHAR(15)

SELECT @name  = NULLIF(p.name,''), @home_phone = NULLIF(p.home_phone,'')
FROM person p --WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE p.person_id = @person_id;

SET @variable_out = 
'Report: ' 
+ ISNULL('Name: ' + @name, 'Name: not found')
+ CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
+ ISNULL('Phone #: ' + @home_phone, 'Phone #: not found')
+ CHAR(13)+CHAR(10);
```

Note:

1. or, you can use for @name & @home_phone variables the same data type like as @variable_out variable (ex. VARCHAR).
2. [NOLOCK pros & cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nolock?sort=votes).

Comment: Ahh, wonderful! I had to adjust the syntax a tiny bit, but this is much better than what I was coming up with. Thank you!